# Determine Groups and Children In Collection

Tags: c#, collections

I am currently looking into improving code efficiency while working with a flat string collection in C#. The strings in this collection can be considered a "group" or a "child".

The problem is that the API for this collection is exposed in such a way that the type of each String in the collection is not directly retrievable and must be determined through other properties.

An example collection:

```
[0] Group Item
[1] Child Item
[2] Child Item
[3] Child Item
[4] Child Item
[5] Group Item
[6] Child Item
[7] Child Item
[8] Group Item
[9] Child Item
[10] Child Item
[11] Child Item
```

For the collection the following is true:

- Position 0 is always a group item
- There can be 0 to N child items between two group items
- The content of the string does not indicate if a string is a child or a group

The following data is available to determine group/child types:

- **ItemCount** (The total amount of strings in the collection)
- **GroupCount** (The total amount of group strings in the collection)
- **GetChildCount(int groupIndex)** (The amount of child items after the group with groupIndex before the next group item)

The data  I need to determine is:

- **Group position** (The position of a group item based on its zero based index. For example: The group index of 2 should return position 8 from the example collection)
- **Child position** (The position of a child item based on its zero based group index and child index. For example: The group index of 0 and child index of 3 should return position 4 from the example collection, and a group index of 2 and a child index of 0 should return position 9)
- The reverse of the above (The indexes for the positions)

Currently I have created up the following methods to determine these values:

```
public bool IsGroupPosition(int position)
{
    int currPosition = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < GroupCount;i++)
    {
        if(currPosition < position)
        {
            currPosition = currPosition + (GetChildrenCount(i) + 1); //Go to next group item in collection
            continue;
        }
        else if(currPosition > position)
        {
            return false; //We passed the position, this is no group item
        }
        else
        {
            return true; //The position is equal to a group position
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public bool IsChildPosition(int position)
{
    int currPosition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < GroupCount; i++)
    {
        if (currPosition == position)
        {
            return false; 
        }
        else if (currPosition > position)
        {
            return true; //We passed the position, this is a child
        }
        else 
        {
            currPosition = currPosition + (GetChildrenCount(i) + 1); //Go to next group in collection
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public int GetGroupIndexForPosition(int position)
{
    int currPosition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= GroupCount; i++)
    {
        int nextGroupPos = currPosition + (GetChildrenCount(i) + 1);
        if (nextGroupPos > position)
        {
            return i;
        }
        currPosition = nextGroupPos;
    }
    return -1;
}

public int GetChildIndexForPosition(int position)
{
    int currPosition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < GroupCount; i++)
    {
        int nextGroupPos = currPosition + (GetChildrenCount(i) + 1);
        if (nextGroupPos > position)
        {
            return (position - currPosition) - 1;
        }
        currPosition = nextGroupPos;
    }
    return -1;
}


public int GetPositionForGroup(int groupIndex)
{
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < groupIndex; i++)
    {
        position += (GetChildrenCount(i) + 1);
    }
    return position;
}

public int GetPositionForChild(int groupIndex, int childIndex)
{
    return GetPositionForGroup(groupIndex) + childIndex;
}
```

It's basically enumerating through the collection by a GetChildrenCount(i) amount of steps. 
And while these methods seem to work fine in terms of functionality, I was wondering if I overlooked something and if there are more efficient ways to determine the group and child positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a professional C# programmer, so I will review the algorithm only:

You can preprocess in linear time the group/child list such that the queries run in <strike>amortised</strike> exact constant time, and that is how:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GroupChildIndex
{
    public const bool GROUP = true;
    public const bool CHILD = false;

    private IDictionary<int, int> groupMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    private IDictionary<int, IDictionary<int, int>> childMap = new Dictionary<int, IDictionary<int, int>>();
    private HashSet<int> childIndexSet = new HashSet<int>();
    private HashSet<int> groupIndexSet = new HashSet<int>();

    public GroupChildIndex(List<bool> list)
    {
        int groupIndex = -1;
        int childIndex = 0;
        int currentIndex = 0;

        foreach (bool token in list)
        {
            if (token == GROUP)
            {
                groupMap[++groupIndex] = currentIndex;
                groupIndexSet.Add(currentIndex);
                childIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!childMap.ContainsKey(groupIndex))
                {
                    childMap[groupIndex] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                }

                childMap[groupIndex][childIndex++] = currentIndex;
                childIndexSet.Add(currentIndex);
            }

            currentIndex++;
        }
    }

    public int GetPositionForGroup(int groupIndex)
    {
        return groupMap[groupIndex];
    }

    public int GetPositionForChild(int groupIndex, int childIndex)
    {
        return childMap[groupIndex][childIndex];
    }

    public bool IsChildPosition(int position)
    {
        return childIndexSet.Contains(position);
    }

    public bool IsGroupPosition(int position)
    {
        return groupIndexSet.Contains(position);
    }
}
```

And the demo driver:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GroupChildIndexer
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<bool> list = new List<bool>()
            {
                GroupChildIndex.GROUP,
                GroupChildIndex.CHILD,
                GroupChildIndex.CHILD,
                GroupChildIndex.CHILD,
                GroupChildIndex.CHILD,

                GroupChildIndex.GROUP,
                GroupChildIndex.CHILD,
                GroupChildIndex.CHILD,
                GroupChildIndex.GROUP,
                GroupChildIndex.CHILD,

                GroupChildIndex.CHILD,
                GroupChildIndex.CHILD
            };

            GroupChildIndex gci = new GroupChildIndex(list);
            Console.WriteLine(gci.GetPositionForGroup(2));
            Console.WriteLine(gci.GetPositionForChild(0, 3));
            Console.WriteLine(gci.GetPositionForChild(2, 0));

            // Yes to these.
            Console.WriteLine(gci.IsChildPosition(4));
            Console.WriteLine(gci.IsChildPosition(9));

            // No to these.
            Console.WriteLine(gci.IsChildPosition(0));
            Console.WriteLine(gci.IsChildPosition(5));

            // Yes to these.
            Console.WriteLine(gci.IsGroupPosition(0));
            Console.WriteLine(gci.IsGroupPosition(5));

            // No to these.
            Console.WriteLine(gci.IsGroupPosition(4));
            Console.WriteLine(gci.IsGroupPosition(9));
        }
    }
}
```

(The above returns 8, 4, and 9.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you started with `groupIndex = -1;` and used `++groupIndex` to increment the index, you wouldn't need to `groupIndex - 1` later. I think it would be cleaner and usually each index is out of range first, this is `-1`.

Comment: Same with `currentIndex` --> `groupMap[++groupIndex] = ++currentIndex;`

Comment: @t3chb0t Thanks, mate! I will address this issue, but a little bit later.

Comment: Preproccessing seems like a improvement over the current code. Will look into implementing this. I will probably have to replace the `if(token == GROUP)` checks etc. in your code with a iteration like in the original setup to identify the group/child items for preprocessing.

Comment: @t3chb0t Done! I did not get the `++currentIndex` though.

Comment: Looks good without the `-1` here and there now but I cannot give you another +1 ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t No problemos. It was a day of multiple +1's. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a minor point as [coderodde](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153144/22816) has already provided an example of preprocessing but I think it's slightly more than a comment on that answer.

Processing your list of strings into a data structure is definitely the way to be more efficient (I.e. only going through the list once) but it also gives you more chance for error checking.

e.g.

```
public int GetPositionForChild(int groupIndex, int childIndex)
{
    return GetPositionForGroup(groupIndex) + childIndex;
}
```

You aren't checking whether it's a valid child index or not. You could do that with your current code but it becomes more complex. Imagine instead:

```
public int GetPositionForChild(int groupIndex, int childIndex)
{
    // groups could be an array or a dictionary
    Group targetGroup = this.groups[groupIndex];       
    if (targetGroup.Children.Length < childIndex + 1)
    {
        // child doesn't exist. Throw a good error here.
    } 
    return targetGroup.Position + childIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty minor I would consider simplify

```
public int GetGroupIndexForPosition(int position)
```

To return null if it is not a group

```
public int? GetGroupIndexForPosition(int position)
```

Then

```
public bool IsChildPosition(int position) 
{
     return (GetGroupIndexForPosition(int position) == null);
}
```

Not wasting much processing and less test.

I think you can do everything with two dictionaries
Only one lookup is not O(1)

forward lookup GroupID to Absolute Position
and a reverse lookup Absolute Position to GroupID

```
private static int? GetGroupIndexForPosition(int pos)
{
    if (pos < 0)
        return null;
    if (pos >= positionTotalCount)
        return null;
    if (absParPosToGroup.ContainsKey(pos))
        return absParPosToGroup[pos];
    else
    {
        // we have a child 
        // save some space by only storing parent and still is close to O(1)
        KeyValuePair<int, int>? parrentPos = absParPosToGroup.Where(x => x.Key < pos).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
        if (parrentPos == null)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("parerntPod == null");
        return ((KeyValuePair< int, int>)parrentPos).Key;
    }
}
private static bool? IsParent(int pos)
{
    if (pos < 0)
        return null;
    if (pos >= positionTotalCount)
        return null;
    return (absParPosToGroup.ContainsKey(pos)); 
}
private static bool? IsChild(int pos)
{
    bool? isParent = IsParent(pos);
    if (isParent == null)
        return null;
    return !isParent;
}
private static int? GetPositionForGroup(int groupID)
{
    if (groupID < 0)
        return null;
    if (groupID >= groupCount)
        return null;
    return groupToParPos[groupID];
}
public int? GetChildIndexForPosition(int position)
{
    int? getGroupIndexForPosition = GetGroupIndexForPosition(position);
    if (getGroupIndexForPosition == null)
        return null;
    int? parentPos = GetPositionForGroup((int)getGroupIndexForPosition);
    if (parentPos == null)
        return null;
    return position - (int)parentPos;
}
public int? GetPositionForChild(int groupIndex, int childIndex)
{
    int? getPositionForGroup = GetPositionForGroup(groupIndex);
    if (getPositionForGroup == null)
        return null;
    if (childIndex > groupSize[childIndex])
        return null;
    return (int)getPositionForGroup + childIndex;
}
private static Dictionary<int, int> groupSize = null;
private static int groupCount = 100;
private static Dictionary<int, int> groupToParPos = null;
private static Dictionary<int, int> absParPosToGroup = null;
private static int positionTotalCount = 0;
public static int? GetChildCount(int groupID)
{
    if (groupID < 0)
        return null;
    if (groupID >= groupCount)
        return null;
    if (groupSize == null)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Dictionary<int, int> groupSize = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        int absPos = 0;
        int childCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
        {
            childCount = rand.Next(10);
            groupSize.Add(i, childCount);
            groupToParPos.Add(i, absPos);
            absParPosToGroup.Add(absPos, i);
            absPos += 1 + childCount;
        }
        positionTotalCount = absPos - 1;
    }
    return groupSize[groupID];
}
```